# Is it possible to load different views using page view controllers?

Tags: objective-c

Hi i am a beginner in objective c. Is it possible to load different views(different .xib files ) when we swipe ,using page controller ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

The `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` requires an `UIViewControlelr` from its delegate methods.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

You could initialize the different view controller before returning it for your requirements.